# Добавить тег title если его нет вообще

Tags: php

У меня есть функция, которая находит и заменяет тег title (можно заменить, можно оставить существующий)

```
function renderTitle($math) {
   $title = empty($_POST["title"]) ? $math[1] : $_POST["title"];
   return "<title>{$title}</title>";
}
// Находим title и заменяем его на свой 
$page_source = preg_replace_callback('/\<title\>(.*?)\<\/title\>/si', 'renderTitle', $page_source);
```

Пожалуйста, помогите изменить функцию таким образом, чтобы она умела создавать тег title если его нет вообще, к примеру, создавала его после открывающего `<head>`

В том случае если title есть, оставлять все без изменений, т.е. не заменять его на дефолтный.

Спасибо!

Comment: Просто принимайте title параметром
function renderTitle($data, $title = "some title") {
//ваш код
}
Так сможете всегда отображать title, придёт или нет уже не нужно проверять.
Чаще всего в MVC у вас есть уже переменная $title в head в layuot-шаблоне и вызывается $this->title = $other_title;

Comment: Изменил на function renderTitle($data, $title = "some title") { - на сайте где не задан title он не появился, что-то я не до конца понял.

Comment: В главном шаблоне используйте переменную $title. ...<head><title>$title<title></head>... Когда "рисуете" страницу, туда передавайте $title, если ничего не пришло, то переменная запишет дефолтное значение(например название сайта), иначе передаёте другое значение... Вы в рамках MVC создаёте? Делать поиск и замену title при создании страницы весьма странное решение. Вообще не понятна логика ловить title в $_POST запросе.

Comment: Теперь понял. Это не совсем мне подходит, в том и дело, что я ловлю title из post запроса с сайта который мне не принадлежит и я за ранее не знаю, есть ли там title.

Comment: А js использовать можно для этих целей?